# Icon doesn't show up in the CAB installer

Tags: deployment, cab, smart-device

I have added icon.ico file (custom made) in my VS project for smart device application. I also created a CAB installer project. The icon.ico is supposedly automatically appears as a shortcut icon, but it doesn't work for me. Do I have to add icon.ico to my CAB installer project manually?

Comment: how did u created a cab project.. explain steps?..
u should add it in installer as primary output

Answer (score 0):

it appeared automatically, I guess VS was caching it.